# How to pass variables from JavaScript to CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I use the following code to send values to a server (PHP script) to take action accordingly.

JS code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/application/helpers/fb_login_assist.php",
    data: {fbname: name, 
           fbid: id, 
           fbemail: email, 
           fbgender: gender,               
           fbimageURL: imageURL},              
    success: function(data){        
    console.log("Data sent to server");
    confirm("You have successfully logged in with FB");
    window.location.reload();       
    }
});
```

It worked completely fine before I moved to CodeIgniter. However I'm confused no how to save the details in DB or fetch data from DB in CodeIgniter.

P.S. I'm new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: may be problem in your url use base_url() and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the absolute path in CI

```
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/controller/update_function",
 // path to the controller 
data: {fbname: name, 
       fbid: id, 
       fbemail: email, 
       fbgender: gender,               
       fbimageURL: imageURL},              
success: function(data){        
console.log("Data sent to server");
confirm("You have successfully logged in with FB");
window.location.reload();       
}
});
```

the problem is only with your path

> use **base_url()** - for that you will need to check the url helper
>
> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

// your PHP file for controller create Controller.php

```
 class Controller extends CI_Controller
 {  
      public function update_function()
      {
         // load your model here 
        $this->load->model("Controller_model");

      }
 }
```

// your PHP file for Model create Controller_model.php

```
class Controller_model extends CI_Model
{
   public function update_data()   
   {
        // use database for updating values using post
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with my base URL. I'm confused on how to use controller to get the value from the entities and then send it to the model.

Comment: i have done some changes see the changes in the code

Comment: @krish_cloudnow the post your controller and model code

Comment: see the changes to the answer, it might be helpful